# B2C: Redirect to "sign-up" flow of a "Sign-up or Sign-in" policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Microsoft Recently added the new "sign-up or sign-in" policy to Azure AD B2C.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies/#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy

By default when we direct a user to that page it shows the sign-in workflow.

Sometimes I may want to take a user directly to the sign-up workflow instead.

I don't want to configure two policies (i.e. upload the same banners, templates, backgrounds, redirects, special messages etc) when the content is going to be exactly the same for both.

Is it possible to pass a parameter (or some otherworldly trickery) so that it shows the "sign-up" workflow instead?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why this authentication solution is way way more complicated than a custom one... Almost anything you want to customize brings tons of work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there isn't a query parameter or policy setting that will take the user straight to the local account sign-up pages in a SignUporSignIn policy. Today you would need a separate sign-up policy to direct them directly to sign up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hello.js for Azure B2C with some customization in initialization, which is build for external authentication of google facebook etc. You can also look into the sample from microsoft which works !!  [Azure B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi)